# Connectedness of the complement of a homeomorph of a ball

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $n\geq 2$. My question is in two parts:

1. If $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded and homeomorphic to the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B$ connected? Does the answer depend on the dimension $n$?
2. If $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B$ connected? Does the answer depend on the dimension $n$?${}$

Comment: I'm tempted to say the complement is connected in both cases. Only because the Alexander horned sphere is a standard example to show the complement need not be *simply* connected - and one would think a common example would be known if there existed a $B$ such that its complement was not even connected. Obviously this is just a heuristic argument.

Comment: For question 2, Alexander Duality implies that the complement is path connected in any dimension. I'm not sure about the case of a bounded open ball.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers to both questions are positive, they are applications of Poincare-Alexander duality.

1. Let $U$ be a bounded open subset of $R^n$ and  $n\ge 2$, then connectivity of $R^n\setminus U$ is equivalent to connectivity of $C=S^n\setminus U$, where $S^n$ is the 1-point compactification of $R^n$. Now, $C$ is compact and we can apply duality:
   $$
   {H}_{n-1}(U)\cong {\check{H}}^0(C)\ne 0,
   $$
   if $C$ is not connected. (Here the cohomology is Chech.) Hence, $U$ cannot be contractible if $C$ is not connected. Thus, if $U$ is homeomorphic to open ball then $C$ is connected.
2. Suppose that $B$ is a compact subset of $R^n$ homeomorphic to a closed ball (it suffices to assume contractibility). By duality, you get
   $$
   \tilde{H}_0(R^n \setminus B)\cong H^n(B)=0. 
   $$ 
   Hence, $R^n \setminus B$ is connected.

Comment: Note that question 1 asks for $B$ to be *bounded*.

Comment: @Mike: Thank you, I missed this assumption when I first read the question.

Answer (score 1):

Question 2 can also be answered using Brouwer's topological degree. More precisely, it can be shown that:

> **Theorem:** Let $\Omega_1, \Omega_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be two homeomorphic compact subspaces. Then $\mathbb{R} \backslash \Omega_1$ and $\mathbb{R} \backslash \Omega_2$ have the same number of connected components.

See [Brouwer’s Topological Degree (IV): Jordan Curve Theorem](http://chiasme.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/brouwers-topological-degree-iv-jordan-curve-theorem/).